# Invoke a function based on time in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming, and I want to know how a program can invoke a process based upon time? For example, an alarm clock. How should the alarm be rung at a specific time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Timer object could work well for this, either [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) if general Java or [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) if a Swing GUI. For details on how to use either of these, I invite you to check out their API's (links in this answer). Also Swing Timer has a [decent tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) if you are going to go that route.

Comment: @backTangent: if any thing I've posted doesn't make sense, please ask!